Use MiniSearch with Lastest Minizinc
Just try to use MiniSearch with Minizinc 2.8.3
Maybe std in MiniSearch is out of date , when using MiniSearch  with --stdlib-dir , error coming with "MiniZinc: internal error: Error occurred when executing FZN solver with command "ortools -a C:\Users\Cubism\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8C9E.tmp"."
When copy the MiniSearch definition to latest Minizinc std , the error comes to
"\MiniZinc/share/minizinc/std/writes_seq.mzn:18:
function array[$$X] of var int: writes_seq(
....
C:\Program Files\MiniZinc/share/minizinc/std/writes_seq.mzn:26:
} in O;
^
Error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file"
is there any way to use minisearch with Minizinc 2.8.3

No, MiniSearch was built as an adaptation, now kept in a different repository from the MiniZinc compiler, and has not been kept up to date with the changes in the MiniZinc compiler. The last changes in MiniSearch are from 2016.
Depending on your need, you can try the experimental support for "meta-search on restart", supported by both the Chuffed and Gecode solvers.
